# read json object clean and sanitize for database storage

Tags: php, json, ajax

Hi I need to send JSON data to my php script and to unpack, clean and sanitize it for insertion in a database the problem is that I do not know how to get the data to the php script and read, it says that the index is undefined.
This is what the ajax request looks like

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save.php",
        data:{param:my_people}, 
        success: function(data){
        //success here means ajax call succeeded, not that the data works
    alert(data);
    }
    });
```

This is what my php looks like

```
 $data = json_decode($_POST['my_people']);
```

The truth is I really do not know how to work with JSON ajax and php. Any help is highly welcome!

Comment: Are you echoing $data ?

Comment: 1) How do you know that the data is sent to `save.php` as JSON instead of the more typical `key1=val1&key2=val2` format? 2)  What do you see if you do `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: it sends me an error an it says that the index was not found

Comment: Is it possible to unpack the object directly and save its value in a php array  that I will manage to pass to the php script instead of sending it through ajax because it just does not work for me?

Comment: As i know it would become `$data = $_POST['param']` mypeople is taken from js side and param is for your php script.

Comment: This the answer I get invariably Undefined index: param but I do not know why any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If your variable `my_people` from Javasript is valid,
`$_POST['param']` should contain `my_people` datas....

Did you try to write
`die(json_ecode($_POST));` or `die(json_ecode($_GET));`
in the **first line** of your `save.php` to see what is coming from Ajax ?

aahh.. the `save.php` file that you are editing
and your code using `$.ajax` is on the same directory ?